# trying to understand the method_exists function of PHP

Tags: php, rest

This is the [tutorial](http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/) I am studying in order to set up a RESTfull interface in my web app-it is an appointments closing web app. The write of the tutorial in order establish the functionality of the interface writes an abstact class where in it there a public function **processAPI**.You will find this function in the section titled **Completing the Abstract Class.**

This function uses the method_exists PHP function to check for the existence of a method...and here are my 2 questions:

1. What the int means in front of the method_exists-the PHP manual does not mention anything relevant about such thing.
2. Since we have already written this method what is the point checking if it exists or not?Unless of course I miss something.

Answer (score 2):

That tutorial is using [type casting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) to convert the result of `method_exists` to an integer, and then seeing if it is greater than 0:

```
if ((int)method_exists($this, $this->endpoint) > 0)
```

Which is kind of silly. The `method_exists` function already returns a boolean, so you can just do:

```
if (method_exists($this, $this->endpoint))
```

The reason for calling `method_exists` is so that you can dynamically call the appropriate PHP method based on the web service request.

Comment: when you say web service request you mean PUT,GET etc?And for the rest of your comments I do not quite get it, I will study the code again.I mean I understand what are you trying to say but I cannot understand how this achieved with the specific code.

Comment: A user hits `/api/v1/recipe`. You need to first ensure that you have a `recipe()` method defined in your code to handle that request, and if so, call it.

Comment: So,if I get correctly.In REST the url must contain the method in question.There is an important note to make about the app I am making.I am following this tutorial here http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/08/05/building-a-shared-calendar-with-backbone-js-and-fullcalendar-a-step-by-step-tutorial/.                   I am afraid I am not doing what I should be doing to make the app RESTfull.More specifically the user arrives at calendar.php(where the calndar is shown)and backbone is used to GET/POST events to an events.php page.But the URL does not display any method.

Comment: @DimitrisPapageorgiou Of course the url must contain the method in question _in order to work properly_. The point is that you can't trust your users to always follow that rule, so you'd better check to make sure.

Comment: Thanks for the help for now...I will make a different question that will seek some more help specifically-to make my App RESTfull.But for concluding-and tell me if I am wrong-the tutorial I mention in the beginning(Creating a RESTfull API with PHP),does it assume that URL will contain the method?

Comment: Yes it does assume that. But it also _validates_ just in case it doesn't. That way you can handle the error and provide a friendly error message back, rather than generating a fatal PHP error by trying to call a method that doesn't exist, if someone messes up.

Comment: then,my main issue at this moment is to tie  these 2 tutorials:http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/  and  http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/08/05/building-a-shared-calendar-with-backbone-js-and-fullcalendar-a-step-by-step-tutorial/...but as I said I will make a different question about it as this question was for a different reason and this,was answered.